# How to use the Windows command line to select files with a certain tag?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a folder with lots of JPEG files. The JPEG files have different "tags" written by the camera like "hdr", "pano", and "single".

[image: file properties]

I want to create a batch file that selects all files with a certain tag and then moves all of those files to a certain directory.

```
move .\100MEDIA\(all files with tag "pano") .\Panos
```

I'm unable to determine what the syntax will be to select files with a certain "tag."

Comment: This superuser item about querying file information from the system may help: https://superuser.com/questions/1588480/is-there-a-way-to-query-file-details-from-a-windows-cmd-prompt